# Error FB.XFBML.parse comment box facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

Hi I have this javascript code:

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {
    $imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');
    if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred.resolve().promise();}
    var dfds = [];  
    $imgs.each(function(){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        dfds.push(dfd);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){dfd.resolve();}
        img.src = this.src;
    });
    return $.when.apply($,dfds);
}
  var disc = function(div,of){
  $(div).hide();  
  $('#loading').show();
  var ajax = $.ajax({url : of, type : "GET", cache: false});
  ajax
    .done(function(response){
      Commons.sorDone(div, response);

    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('.fb-comments'));
       twttr.widgets.load();  

    })
    .fail(function(){
      Commons.sorFail(div); 
    });
  }

  Commons = {
    sorDone : function (div, response) {
      $(div).html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $(div).show();
      });
    },
  }
```

The code does is load content via a button in a div dynamically. While charging the content shows a gif preload.

Well, that content is no social buttons facebook and twitter and box of facebook comments also show that in order to be parsed with FB.XFBML.parse

So far so good, but the problem is that sometimes appear facebook comments and sometimes the empty space and comments are not displayed.

where it could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved just when placing below shows the div at the end.

For if someone helps. No longer fails, it will always spot the parse.

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {
    $imgs = this.find('img[src!=""]');
    if (!$imgs.length) {return $.Deferred.resolve().promise();}
    var dfds = [];  
    $imgs.each(function(){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        dfds.push(dfd);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){dfd.resolve();}
        img.src = this.src;
    });
    return $.when.apply($,dfds);
}
  var disc = function(div,of){
  $(div).hide();  
  $('#loading').show();
  var ajax = $.ajax({url : of, type : "GET", cache: false});
  ajax
    .done(function(response){
      Commons.sorDone(div, response);



    })
    .fail(function(){
      Commons.sorFail(div); 
    });
  }

  Commons = {
    sorDone : function (div, response) {
      $(div).html(response).imagesLoaded().then(function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $(div).show();
  FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('.fb-comments'));
       twttr.widgets.load();  

      });
    },
  }
```